# CURL returns "Unknown SSL protocol error"

Tags: linux, web-services, ssl, curl

I've looked at several similar questions here, but none of them have helped me.  I want to connect to a web service that uses single-sign-on via an RSA SecurID keyfob.  I start by trying to load any cookies provided by the initial GET request.  Here's my command:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" -L -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -v -X GET \
  https://sso.example.com/sso/login.htm
```

I get this in response:

```
* About to connect() to sso.example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 23.12.245.199... connected
* Connected to sso.example.com (23.12.245.199) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs/
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sso.example.com:443
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to sso.example.com:443
```

Here's what I'm using:

```
# curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8j zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.10
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
#  more /etc/*-release
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 3
# uname -r
3.0.101-0.21-default
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is OpenSSL in your client that has a problem to understand what the server is saying and it errors out because of that.

You can sometimes work around these kinds of issues by forcing curl to speak SSLv3 ([-3](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-3)), TLS1.0 ([-1](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-1)) or even SSLv2 ([-2](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-2))

... it is also conceivable that your severely outdated versions of curl and OpenSSL simply have a bug or two that cause this and that you can fix this problem by upgrading to modern versions (and then also fix the numerous security problems your versions contain).